# How to add more items to an array based on how much free space is left on screen

Tags: angular

I have a `div` which is supposed to contain some boxes. width of the `div` depends on the screen size. On the other hand, I want to add *enough* boxes to the `div` container, so that the `div` does not have considerable free space. Picture below, is the desired output. There are 7 boxes and there is no more room for another box:
[image]

Code to implement the above picture is sth like this:

```
<div class="date-box" *ngFor="let day of days; ">
    <div>{{day}}</div>
</div>
```

I need to know the width of the container `div` and based on that, calculate how many boxes I should add!
How can I do that?

So far, I've tried using combination of `@ViewChild` and `ElementRef` to achieve what I want, and it worked out.
I used `@ViewChild` to get the width of `div` and calculate how many boxes I need.
The problem is that, that solution is considered as accessing `DOM` in `ts` files, which I'm supposed to avoid.
Is there any other solution? 
Is there any way to detect if there is free space left and call a method which adds more items to an array (`days` array) which result in more boxes being rendered on the view?

Answer (score 0):

I had to tackle this question few weeks ago and here is what I came up with.

```html
<div class="date-box-container" #container>
    <div class="date-box" *ngFor="let day of days" #dayElement>
        <div>{{day}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can retrieze the `#container` div and `#dayElement` divs in you component class respectively with `@ViewChild()`and `@ViewChildren()`.

I decided to use [resize-observer-polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/resize-observer-polyfill) dependency to observe every size changes in your `container`div. Just add this bit of code in the `ngAfterViewInit()` method to be sure that you DOM is already loaded.

(Don't forget to add an `overflow: hidden;` on your container div to make the coming computation work)

```js
const ro = new ResizeObserver((entries, observer) => {
    for (const entry of entries) {
        // Here you must call you computation method that I'll describe later
    }
});

ro.observe(this.container);
```

Then, you only need a quite simple computation using the parent div `offsetWidth` and the sum of their children widths to hide the elements that must be hidden by storing a boolean property in the `day` object and `*ngIf="day.visible"`in your template.

I hope my explanation was clear enough, if you're stuck don't hesitate to share a working demo showing your issues!

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved a lot easier in CSS. Just add ALL the boxes and use `flex-wrap: wrap` in combination with `overflow: hidden` to wrap any items out of sight that don't fit:

```html
<div class="button-bar">
  <div class="button-bar-item" *ngFor="let day of days">
    <div class="date-box">
      <div>{{day}}</day>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.button-bar {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  flex-wrap: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.button-bar-button {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Because the height of the `button-bar-item` is 100% when the bar is full the next buttons will be wrapped out of sight since the overflow of `button-bar` is hidden. If you don't like the layout there's other values for `justify-content` such as `space-between` that might look better.

Solutions that depend on resize events can cause drastic overheads!